# How to make @ManyToOne work with Spring Lemon?

Tags: spring-lemon

I have an existing Spring MVC + Spring Security + Thymeleaf project. My intention is to add Spring Lemon functionalities to it.

I followed [Spring Lemon Getting Started guide](https://www.gitbook.com/book/naturalprogrammer/spring-lemon-getting-started/details), and built a Lemon-powered project. It runs successfully.

Now I'm trying to copy my entities into the Lemon project.

Things go well until I modify my entities to extend VersionedEntity, as said in the documentation.
Then I get this error :

![Error]https://i.stack.imgur.com/snz86.png

Looks like VersionedEntity is incompatible with my ManyToOne relationships. And when I delete those relationships, the problem disappears.

How do i get the tables generated with those JPA annotations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even extending AbstractAuditable didn't solve it. With the help of [Sanjay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1075051/sanjay), I understood that when you extend VersionedEntity or LemonEntity, you don't need the Id field in your entity class anymore. Then I deleted it, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

`VersionedEntity` is a lightweight class to support versioning, which extends `LemonEntity`, which in turn extends Spring Data JPA's `AbstractAuditable`. So, to pin point where could be the problem, I think you could try extending your classes straight from from `LemonEntity` or `AbstractAuditable`, and then see if the issue still remains.

Let's see what you find. If the issue comes even if your entities extend `AbstractAuditable`, maybe `AbstractAuditable` isn't compatible with `@ManyToOne` (assuming your code is fine). In that case, I think raising it with Spring Data JPA guys (either add `spring-data-jpa` tag to this question or create a separate question with that tag) will help.